# Compile locally asymptote in a TeXlive compatible way

Tags: texlive, asymptote

Some time ago, [I wrote a sketch of a local compilation and installation of `asymptote` in (what I believe to be) a TeXLive compatible way](https://sourceforge.net/p/asymptote/discussion/409349/thread/a0a3876b/). This was back in 2010 (ubuntu 10.10 and TeXLive vanilla 2010). The steps were:

```
sudo apt-get install subversion autoconf gcc g++ bison flex make libzip-dev zlib1g-dev cdbs debhelper libfftw3-dev libreadline5-dev libncurses5-dev libgsl0-dev libsigsegv-dev freeglut3 freeglut3-dev texinfo
wget http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/asymptote.zip
unzip asymptote.zip
cd asymptote
./configure --with-latex=$HOME/texmf/tex/latex --with-context=$HOME/texmf/tex/context/third --datadir=$HOME/texmf --prefix=$HOME --datarootdir=$HOME/texmf/doc --with-docdir=$HOME/texmf/doc/asymptote
LC_ALL=POSIX make all
```

Those lines copy the binaries in $HOME/bin, the required asymptote files in $HOME/texmf/asymptote, the documentation in $HOME/texmf/doc/asymptote and the .sty in $HOME/texmf/tex/latex.

1. Is it the/a right way to do?
2. Dependencies for asymptote seems to have changed over the year: where can I find an extensive list of what is needed to compile asymptote (with full options, that is with the gnu scientific library and fft)? A "big" list of debian and/or arch packages would be great.

Comment: I installed this morning on a new Debian Sid 64 bits. It is not a very well Texlive compatible way. I installed `install-info subversion autoconf gcc g++ bison flex make libzip-dev zlib1g-dev cdbs debhelper libfftw3-dev libglu1-mesa libglu1-mesa-dev freeglut3-dev freeglut3 libgsl2 libgsl-dev fftw-dev  libncurses5-dev libreadline-dev`. I installed also `gc-7.6.0`and used `CFLAGS=-O2`. At last for `make install`, a Perl error, which is solved by `export PERL5LIB=/home/guibe/tmp/asymptote/asymptote/doc/FAQ/` (please replace by the appropriate directory).